# How do I set a cursor css for text inside li element?

Tags: css

How do I set a cursor css for text inside li element?

The cursor is an arrow when only on the li, outside of any text inside. When i move it to the text it turns into a text cursor. I want the cursor to stay the same all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li {
    cursor:default;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2NMfQ/1)**

You can see the various cursor options at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Answer (score 1):

Try CSS [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) porperty:

```
li {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Some possible values:

- auto
- none
- default: [image]
- context-menu: [image]
- help: [image]
- pointer: [image]
- progress: [image]
- wait: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the cursor property to default in the list style tag!

```
        li {
        cursor:default;
        }
```

Go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) for more information on the cursor property.
Or go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=alias) to view a really user friendly list that lets you view all the available cursors and copy the code directly from the webpage.